# How to reduce amount of Lists respectively how to use lists multiple times

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, copy

I have problems to simplify my code with many maps and lists.

I have to read and save many many results from one big Excel file.

My code works and does what it should. But I do not like it at all because of the many lists and maps.

Below you can see my code:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getResultFromExcelFile() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> allResults = new ArrayList<>();


    Map<String, Object> previousYearResult = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> actYearResult = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> plusOneYearResult = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> plusTwoYearResult = new HashMap<>();


    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> previousYearResultActList = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> actYearResultPlanList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> actYearResultFcList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> actYearResultActList = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> plusOneYearResultPlanList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> plusOneYearResultFcList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> plusOneYearResultActList = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> plusTwoYearResultPlanList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> plusTwoYearResultFcList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> plusTwoYearResultActList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 20; i < 67; i++) {
        for (int j = 526; j < 1141; j++) {
            if (i < BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_MINUS_1 + 12) {
                //act
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 1) {
                    previousYearResultActList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
            }
            if (i >= BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_0 && i < BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_0 + 12) {
                //plan
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 3) {
                    actYearResultPlanList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
                //fc
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 2) {
                    actYearResultFcList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
                //act
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 1) {
                    actYearResultActList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
            }

            if (i >= BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_1 && i < BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_1 + 12) {
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 3) {
                    //plan
                    plusOneYearResultPlanList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 2) {
                    //fc
                    plusOneYearResultFcList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 1) {
                    //act
                    plusOneYearResultActList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
            }
            if (i >= BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_2 && i < BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_2 + 12) {
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 3) {
                    //plan
                    plusTwoYearResultPlanList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 2) {
                    //fc
                    plusTwoYearResultFcList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 1) {
                    //act
                    plusTwoYearResultActList.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    previousYearResult.put("actList", previousYearResultActList);

    actYearResult.put("planList", actYearResultPlanList);
    actYearResult.put("fcList", actYearResultFcList);
    actYearResult.put("actList", actYearResultActList);

    plusOneYearResult.put("planList", plusOneYearResultPlanList);
    plusOneYearResult.put("fcList", plusOneYearResultFcList);
    plusOneYearResult.put("actList", plusOneYearResultActList);

    plusTwoYearResult.put("planList", plusTwoYearResultPlanList);
    plusTwoYearResult.put("fcList", plusTwoYearResultFcList);
    plusTwoYearResult.put("actList", plusTwoYearResultActList);


    allResults.add(previousYearResult);
    allResults.add(actYearResult);
    allResults.add(plusOneYearResult);
    allResults.add(plusTwoYearResult);

    return allResults;
}
```

I've tried a lot. Only one list each for Plan Fc and Act. then filled in the loop and put it into the map. Then I cleaned up the lists. But since it was only the reference to the original list, they were also deleted from the map.
So I tried to work with Collections.copy(). But I did not get any further.

My goal is to reduce all ArrayLists to 3, Plan Fc and Act.
So that I don't have to create 3 lists for the previous year, the actual year and the 2 following years.

For example for this condition:

```
 if (i >= BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_0 && i < BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_0 + 12) {...}
```

I want to fill 3 lists and then fill them into the matching map. Empty the 3 lists and fill them again in the next if condition and then pass them into the matching map.

Does anyone have an idea how I can best implement this and thus reduce the number of lists? Thanks You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem the code for three type are very similar. You should create a function to reuse

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> readExcel(int beginColumnYear) {
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 20; i < 67; i++) {
    for (int j = 526; j < 1141; j++) {
        if (i >= beginColumnYear && i < beginColumnYear + 12) {
                if (findFirstDigit(getWorkBook().getNumber(j, 1)) == 3) {
                    list.add(this.buildResultMap(i, j));
                }
                ...
            }
    }     
}
return list;
}

...
actYearResult.put("planList", readExcel(BEGIN_COLUMN_YEAR_0));
...
```

Beside You should optimize the speed and the memory usage of your code

Comment: Thanks, that helped me rethink. I took over your approach and wrote an extra function.

Comment: What exactly do u mean i should do to optimize the speed and memory usage? thought by reducing all the lists it will do this :)

Comment: - a loop inside a loop, your can optimize this part and I think you should consider make your code work asynchronous. 
- the big deal is the memory usage, You said you read from a big excel file and then you load them all into memory, that may lead to outofmemory error.
- optimize is the take time process, I suppose you to research about java asynchronous, memory management, garbage collection, ...